# Nested meta-data in Android manifest?

Tags: android, xml, metadata, android-manifest

I'd like to keep my global project settings in the manifest meta-data, but there are some arrays I'd like to keep there too. I'm not sure if it is possible, but I'd like to do something like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="Categories">
    <item id="5" title="Food" />
    <item id="6" title="Health" />
    <item id="7" title="Garden" />
</meta-data>
```

Can something like this be achieved without storing a multi-valued attribute? For example, I don't want to have to maintain something like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="Categories" android:value="5,Food|6,Health|7,Garden" />
```

I'm storing these configurations so I can clone projects quickly and just change the manifest meta-data. The configurations can get long so the multi-valued attribute would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Use `strings.xml` or your own custom.xml for data or add data to `assets` or `sharedpreferences`.

Comment: I just noticed a `android:resource` in `meta-data`. Can that be useful?

Comment: @JaredBurrows, ok I am willing to create a `configuration.xml`, but I don't think `sharedpreferences` is good for this scenario since it is only static, read-only data and will need it very early in the app lifecycle, not just activities.